# Any idea what Detail-preserving Regularization means ? in context of image processing

Tags: image, image-processing

please help not able to understand this concept.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regularizer is in this context a part of a variational equation which leads, when solved to an image filter which preserves for instance edges, while blurring out the noise everywhere else. Please read about "Total Variation Filter" to catch the concept.